# Determining a group given its quotient

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $K_4$ be the Klein $4$-group and let $C_2$ be the cyclic group of order $2$.

Suppose I know that $K_4 \cong G/C_2$ for some group $G$. Is $G$ unique, and if so, how can I determine what $G$ is?

I know that a possible group $G$ is the quaternion group, but I don't know how to show it.

Comment: All non-cyclic groups of order $8$ have a subgroup with this property.

Comment: How can we see that?

Comment: For the abelian ones, it is just a matter of listing them. For the nonabelian ones, apart from listing them (there are just 2) we can see that the center must have order $2$ and the quotient cannot be cyclic, so it must be as in your case.